# How to change sweetalert button text?

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I want to change the 'Ok' button with 'Select patient' and the 'Cancel' to 'Speed case'. How can I do that?

```
swal({
  text: "Start new case by",
  buttons: true,
  confirmButtonText: "Select Patient?",
  cancelButtonText: "Speed Case?",      
});
```

Comment: The `confirmButtonText` and `cancelButtonText` properties are exactly what you need. You just need to add a `title` property for the alert to appear: https://jsfiddle.net/hfev385s/

Comment: because i am creating two button , this both button redirect to different page sir

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
swal({
  text: "Start new case by",
  buttons: ["Select Patient?", "Speed Case?"],
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me, perhaps because there are multiple forks of sweet-alert named the same (or almost the same) thing: sweetalert2.  And perhaps some people are still using version 1, which _might_ also have multiple forks... I don't know.  If this doesn't work for you either, try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49027425/241142), that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 30):

here is the answer

```
 swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "you want to Cancel Operation!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
```

hope it will work for you

Answer (score 8):

You can use this approach

```
swal({
  text: "Start new case by",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: "Select Patient?",
  cancelButtonText: "Speed Case?",     
  title: 'Title'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',
    icon: 'warning',
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
    buttons: ['yes, forsure', 'no, thanks']
});
```